# label argument in plt.fill_between not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with line plots using:

```
x = np.arange(25,55,5)
y = np.random.randint(10000,50000,6)
y2 = np.random.randint(10000,60000,6)
```

Then the main plotting code is:

```
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')


plt.xlabel("some random ages")
plt.ylabel('some random salaries')
plt.title('whatever')
plt.legend(['first','second'])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y2) 



plt.fill_between(x,y,color = 'blue', alpha = 0.25, where = (y>np.median(y)), interpolate =True, 
                 label = 'above median') 
#Colour blue for salaries more than the median.


plt.fill_between(x,y,color = 'red', alpha = 0.25, where = (y<=np.median(y)), interpolate =True, 
                 label = 'below median')
#Colour red for salaries less than the median.


plt.show()
```

The filling is working as intended, however the plot legends only have the entries specified in  `plt.legend()`. The label argument, which seems to work in the tutorial video I am watching as well as every other site I have seen, does not add the intended labels to the legends. I had the same problem in stack plots, where the tutor, who is using pycharm, used `labels` to add legend to the satckplot, and I had to use `plt.legend` because the `labels` command seemed to do nothing. However here I don't know how to add the legends for the fill colours along with the legends for the main line plots.

I am using the latest version of jupyter notebook and latest python version on macOS Monterey 12.4.

Comment: Try this: `plt.plot(x,y ,label='first');plt.plot(x,y2 ,label='second');plt.legend();`

Comment: This leaves the plot with no legends at all, giving the warning ```No artists with labels found to put in legend.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either specify your `label`s in all places:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.arange(25,55,5)
y = np.random.randint(10000,50000,6)
y2 = np.random.randint(10000,60000,6)

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.plot(x,y, label='red')
plt.plot(x,y2, label='blue') 

#Colour blue for salaries more than the median.
plt.fill_between(x,y,color = 'blue', alpha = 0.25, where = (y>np.median(y)), interpolate =True, 
                 label = 'above median') 


#Colour red for salaries less than the median.
plt.fill_between(x,y,color = 'red', alpha = 0.25, where = (y<=np.median(y)), interpolate =True, 
                 label = 'below median')

plt.xlabel("some random ages")
plt.ylabel('some random salaries')
plt.title('whatever')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

or specify all labels in the legend parameters:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.arange(25,55,5)
y = np.random.randint(10000,50000,6)
y2 = np.random.randint(10000,60000,6)

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y2) 

#Colour blue for salaries more than the median.
plt.fill_between(x,y,color = 'blue', alpha = 0.25, where = (y>np.median(y)), interpolate =True) 

#Colour red for salaries less than the median.
plt.fill_between(x,y,color = 'red', alpha = 0.25, where = (y<=np.median(y)), interpolate =True)

plt.xlabel("some random ages")
plt.ylabel('some random salaries')
plt.title('whatever')
plt.legend(['red', 'blue', 'above', 'below'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the first method is the recommended one (as noted by @JohanC) because it does the job for you and it adds the labels automatically. In the second, you are overwriting what is in the legend. That is what happened in your example -- you defined your labels in the `label` argument and then you passed a list to the `legend` function which overrides your `label`s.

Comment: Note that the first approach is strongly preferable to the second. The second breaks too easily when the plot is tweaked or new elements are added.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what happened in the question. I updated the answer to cover this. Thanks for the tip, @JohanC

Comment: A similar issue can occur when mixing charting libraries like matplotlib with seaborn. This can be resolved by calling `plt.scatter()`, `plt.fill()`, etc with the `label` before calling `sns.lineplot()` etc.